# Error while parsing a JSON with angular 8

Tags: json, angular, parsing

I have a problem when I try to parse a JSON using angular 8; this is my code:

```
  getBandi(){

this.http.get("myURL").subscribe((res) => {
  if (JSON.stringify(res)){   
    var arra = res as any[];
    for(let i=0;i<arra.length;i++){

      console.log(arra[i]["efa6f15d-0028-45e3-b4b4-e35bff160d47"]); 
    }
  }
}, (error) =>{

  alert("Error")
});
}
```

and this is the structure of my jSON (actually is an array of this type):

```
{ 
"efa6f15d-0028-45e3-b4b4-e35bff160d47":{  },
"30c83720-6c74-4373-929c-4c45102c49c5":{  },
"27598461-f4cb-4c80-bff9-23aa50f12c0f":{  },
"f03897c9-d636-4bcb-95bd-fe130f26d4f3":{  },
"8808f9b5-4460-4fcb-b623-83e0ba71f315":{  },
"a158776a-7134-49f4-be57-5388c8d8e5ae":{  },
"ce654fde-2155-4c1b-9609-973a14e212ee":{  },
"c8b2a21b-2b66-4af7-8289-a37db0fdc916":{  },
"caf78a08-2f4f-4561-8c2f-49bb3fb4bc43":{  },
"d9221499-0b6f-4663-a122-1054038fc977":{  },
"5260368d-ed28-4227-a76d-773461ecce68":{  },
"a8d4dab3-94b7-49b9-9ef1-63193fe5b405":{  }
}
```

the problema is that when I try to log the value of this key "efa6f15d-0028-45e3-b4b4-e35bff160d47" I always get

> undefined

this is the output of `JSON.stringfy(res)`:

```
["{\n\t\"efa6f15d-0028-45e3-b4b4-e35bff160d47\": {\n\t\t\"0\": {\n\t\t\t\"file\": \"images\\/in_primo_piano\\/Credito_Imposta_regioni_Mezzogiorno-min.jpg\",\n\t\t\t\"title\": \"\",\n\t\t\t\"link\": \"\",\n\t\t\t\"target\": \"0\",\n\t\t\t\"rel\": \"\",\n\t\t\t\"file2\": \"\",\n\t\t\t\"overlay_effect\": \"\",\n\t\t\t\"caption\": \"\",\n\t\t\t\"width\": 758,\n\t\t\t\"height\": 428\n\t\t}\n\t},\n\t\"30c83720-6c74-4373-929c-4c45102c49c5\": {\n\t\t\"0\": {\n\t\t\t\"file\": \"images\\/headers\\/bonus_investimenti_mezzogiorno-min.jpg\",\n\t\t\t\"title\": \"\",\n\t\t\t\"file2\": \"\",\n\t\t\t\"overlay_effect\": \"\",\n\t\t\t\"caption\": \"\",\n\t\t\t\"width\": 2500,\n\t\t\t\"height\": 300\n\t\t}\n\t},\n\t\"27598461-f4cb-4c80-bff9-23aa50f12c0f\": {\n\t\t\"0\": {\n\t\t\t\"value\": \"<strong>Contributo per l\\u2019acquisto di beni strumentali<\\/strong> <strong>nuovi<\\/strong> destinati a strutture produttive ubicate <strong>nelle regioni del Mezzogiorno.<\\/strong>\"\n\t\t}\n\t},\n\t\"f03897c9-d636-4bcb-95bd-fe130f26d4f3\": {\n\t\t\"0\": {\n\t\t\t\"value\": \"<div style=\\\"text-align: justify;\\\">Le imprese che intendono fruire del credito d\\u2019imposta devono presentare una Comunicazione all\\u2019Agenzia delle Entrate.<\\/div>\\r\\n<div style=\\\"text-align: justify;\\\">L'azienda beneficiaria pu\\u00f2 utilizzare il credito d\\u2019imposta maturato <strong>solo in compensazione<\\/strong> tramite modello F24.<\\/div>\"\n\t\t}\n\t},\n\t\"8808f9b5-4460-4fcb-b623-83e0ba71f315\": {\n\t\t\"0\": {\n\t\t\t\"value\": \"<strong>Credito d\\u2019imposta spettante (in % sull\\u2019investimento effettuato):<\\/strong><br \\/><br \\/><strong><span style=\\\"text-decoration: underline;\\\">REGIONI: Campania, Puglia, Basilicata, Calabria, Sicilia, Sardegna<\\/span><\\/strong><br \\/>\\r\\n<ul>\\r\\n<li>45% per le piccole imprese<\\/li>\\r\\n<li>35% per le medie imprese<\\/li>\\r\\n<li>25% per le grandi imprese<\\/li>\\r\\n<\\/ul>\\r\\n<span style=\\\"text-decoration: underline;\\\"><strong>REGIONI: Molise e Abruzzo<\\/strong><\\/span><br \\/>\\r\\n<ul>\\r\\n<li>30% per le piccole imprese<\\/li>\\r\\n<li>20% per le medie imprese<\\/li>\\r\\n<li>10% per le grandi imprese<\\/li>\\r\\n<\\/ul>\\r\\n<strong>L\\u2019agevolazione spetta per investimenti di importo massimo pari a:<\\/strong><br \\/>\\r\\n<ul>\\r\\n<li><strong>3 milioni<\\/strong> per le piccole imprese<\\/li>\\r\\n<li><strong>10 milioni<\\/strong> per le medie imprese<\\/li>\\r\\n<li><strong>15 milioni<\\/strong> per le grandi imprese<\\/li>\\r\\n<\\/ul>\\r\\n<p>Il Credito D'imposta per gli investimenti nelle Regioni del Mezzogiorno \\u00e8 cumulabile con altre misure quali:<\\/p>\\r\\n<ul>\\r\\n<li><strong>Super-ammortamento del 140%<\\/strong>&nbsp;delle quote di ammortamento e canoni di locazione di beni strumentali per le operazioni effettuate fino al 30\\/06\\/2018.<\\/li>\\r\\n<li><strong>Iper-ammortamento del 250%<\\/strong>&nbsp;sull\\u2019acquisto di beni strumentali nuovi ad alto contenuto tecnologico per l\\u2019anno 2017.<\\/li>\\r\\n<\\/ul>\\r\\n<p><strong>Definizioni:<\\/strong><\\/p>\\r\\n<p><span style=\\\"text-decoration: underline;\\\"><strong>Piccole imprese:<\\/strong><\\/span> occupano meno di 50 persone e realizzano un fatturato annuo o un totale di bilancio annuo non superiore a 10 milioni di \\u20ac.<br \\/><strong><span style=\\\"text-decoration: underline;\\\">Medie imprese<\\/span>: <\\/strong>occupano meno di 250 persone e realizzano un fatturato annuo che non supera i 50 milioni di \\u20ac oppure hanno totale di bilancio annuo non supera i 43 milioni di \\u20ac.<\\/p>\"\n\t\t}\n\t},\n\t\"a158776a-7134-49f4-be57-5388c8d8e5ae\": {\n\t\t\"0\": {\n\t\t\t\"value\": \"<div style=\\\"text-align: justify;\\\">Il credito d'imposta pu\\u00f2 essere concesso per investimenti in <strong>beni strumentali nuovi<\\/strong> <strong>effettuati dall'1\\u00b0 gennaio 2016 e fino al 31 dicembre 2019<\\/strong> per:<\\/div>\\r\\n<ul>\\r\\n<li style=\\\"text-align: justify;\\\">\\r\\n<div>la realizzazione di un nuovo stabilimento<\\/div>\\r\\n<\\/li>\\r\\n<li style=\\\"text-align: justify;\\\">\\r\\n<div>l\\u2019ampliamento di uno stabilimento esistente<\\/div>\\r\\n<\\/li>\\r\\n<li style=\\\"text-align: justify;\\\">\\r\\n<div>la diversificazione della produzione di uno stabilimento<\\/div>\\r\\n<\\/li>\\r\\n<li style=\\\"text-align: justify;\\\">\\r\\n<div>la trasformazione radicale del processo produttivo complessivo di uno stabilimento esistente<\\/div>\\r\\n<\\/li>\\r\\n<li>\\r\\n<div style=\\\"text-align: justify;\\\">la riattivazione di uno stabilimento chiuso o che sarebbe stato chiuso qualora non fosse stato acquisito<\\/div>\\r\\n<\\/li>\\r\\n<\\/ul>\"\n\t\t}\n\t},\n\t\"ce654fde-2155-4c1b-9609-973a14e212ee\": {\n\t\t\"0\": {\n\t\t\t\"value\": \"Possono beneficiare del contributo tutte le aziende con <strong>progetti di investimento localizzati nelle regioni del Mezzogiorno:<\\/strong><br \\/>\\r\\n<ul>\\r\\n<li>Campania<\\/li>\\r\\n<li>Puglia<\\/li>\\r\\n<li>Basilicata<\\/li>\\r\\n<li>Calabria<\\/li>\\r\\n<li>Sicilia<\\/li>\\r\\n<li>Sardegna<\\/li>\\r\\n<li>Molise<\\/li>\\r\\n<li>Abruzzo<\\/li>\\r\\n<\\/ul>\"\n\t\t}\n\t},\n\t\"c8b2a21b-2b66-4af7-8289-a37db0fdc916\": {\n\t\t\"0\": {\n\t\t\t\"value\": \"\"\n\t\t}\n\t},\n\t\"caf78a08-2f4f-4561-8c2f-49bb3fb4bc43\": {\n\t\t\"0\": {\n\t\t\t\"value\": \"Credito D'Imposta\"\n\t\t}\n\t},\n\t\"d9221499-0b6f-4663-a122-1054038fc977\": {\n\t\t\"0\": {\n\t\t\t\"value\": \"Campania, Puglia, Basilicata, Calabria, Sicilia, Sardegna, Molise, Abruzzo\"\n\t\t}\n\t},\n\t\"5260368d-ed28-4227-a76d-773461ecce68\": {\n\t\t\"0\": {\n\t\t\t\"value\": \"Tutti i Settori\"\n\t\t}\n\t},\n\t\"a8d4dab3-94b7-49b9-9ef1-63193fe5b405\": {\n\t\t\"0\": {\n\t\t\t\"value\": \"\"\n\t\t}\n\t}\n}","{\n\t\"efa6f15d-0028-45e3-b4b4-e35bff160d47\": {\n\t\t\"0\": {\n\t\t\t\"file\": \"images\\/in_primo_piano\\/agevolazione-azienda-teaser.jpg\",\n\t\t\t\"title\": \"\",\n\t\t\t\"link\": \"\",\n\t\t\t\"target\": \"0\",\n\t\t\t\"rel\": \"\",\n\t\t\t\"file2\": \"\",\n\t\t\t\"overlay_effect\": \"\",\n\t\t\t\"caption\": \"\",\n\t\t\t\"width\": 600,\n\t\t\t\"height\": 300\n\t\t}\n\t},\n\t\"30c83720-6c74-4373-929c-4c45102c49c5\": {\n\t\t\"0\": {\n\t\t\t\"file\": \"images\\/in_primo_piano\\/agevolazione-aziende-full.jpg\",\n\t\t\t\"title\": \"\",\n\t\t\t\"file2\": \"\",\n\t\t\t\"overlay_effect\": \"\",\n\t\t\t\"caption\": \"\",\n\t\t\t\"width\": 2500,\n\t\t\t\"height\": 300\n\t\t}\n\t},\n\t\"27598461-f4cb-4c80-bff9-23aa50f12c0f\": {\n\t\t\"0\": {\n\t\t\t\"value\": \"<strong>CONTRIBUTO PER INNOVAZIONE TECNOLOGICA E SVILUPPO NUOVI PRODOTTI E SERVIZI,<span style=\\\"color: #993366;\\\">&nbsp;FINO A 20 MILIONI DI EURO ALL'ANNO,<\\/span> IMMEDIATAMENTE FRUIBILE DA TUTTE LE AZIENDE per le annualit\\u00e0 2015-2020<br \\/><\\/strong>\"\n\t\t}\n\t},\n\t\"f03897c9-d636-4bcb-95bd-fe130f26d4f3\": {\n\t\t\"0\": {\n\t\t\t\"value\": \"Il credito d\\u2019imposta dovr\\u00e0 essere indicato nella dichiarazione dei redditi relativa al periodo d\\u2019imposta di sostenimento dei costi agevolati.\"\n\t\t}\n\t},\n\t\"8808f9b5-4460-4fcb-b623-83e0ba71f315\": {\n\t\t\"0\": {\n\t\t\t\"value\": \"<p>Il contributo, sotto forma di credito d'imposta, spetta nell\\u2019importo <strong>massimo annuale di 20.000.000 \\u20ac<\\/strong> per ciascuna annualit\\u00e0<strong> dal 2015 al 2020<\\/strong>&nbsp;per spese sostenute inerenti attivit\\u00e0 di sviluppo, innovazione tecnologica, progettazione e ricerca.<\\/p>\\r\\n<p>Le imprese possono <strong>recuperare fino al 50% delle spese<\\/strong> sostenute per progetti di ricerca e sviluppo.<\\/p>\\r\\n<ul>\\r\\n<li>50 % della spesa incrementale relativa al personale altamente qualificato e alla ricerca commissionata a terzi;<\\/li>\\r\\n<li>25 % della spesa incrementale delle quote di ammortamento degli strumenti e attrezzature nonch\\u00e9 di quella relativa a competenze e personale tecnico.<\\/li>\\r\\n<\\/ul>\\r\\n<p>Il credito di imposta per attivit\\u00e0 di ricerca e sviluppo deve ritenersi fruibile <strong>anche in presenza di altre misure di favore<\\/strong>, salvo che le norme disciplinanti le altre misure non dispongano diversamente.<\\/p>\"\n\t\t}\n\t},\n\t\"a158776a-7134-49f4-be57-5388c8d8e5ae\": {\n\t\t\"0\": {\n\t\t\t\"value\": \"<p>Sono ammissibili tutte le spese relative ad attivit\\u00e0 di <strong>ricerca e sviluppo di nuovi prodotti, progetti sperimentali, processi innovativi e ricerca industriale.<\\/strong><\\/p>\\r\\n<p>In particolare:<\\/p>\\r\\n<ul>\\r\\n<li>la ricerca pianificata, gli studi di fattibilit\\u00e0 e i lavori sperimentali mirati a mettere a punto nuovi prodotti, processi e servizi, o per permettere un miglioramento di quelli gi\\u00e0 prodotti dall\\u2019Impresa;<\\/li>\\r\\n<li>lo sviluppo di piani, progetti o disegni per prodotti, processi o servizi nuovi, modificati, o migliorati;<\\/li>\\r\\n<li>la produzione e il collaudo di nuovi prodotti, processi e servizi<\\/li>\\r\\n<li>progettazione software, multimediale e componentistica digitale;<\\/li>\\r\\n<li>misure, calcolo, certificazioni di prodotto;<\\/li>\\r\\n<\\/ul>\"\n\t\t}\n\t},\n\t\"ce654fde-2155-4c1b-9609-973a14e212ee\": {\n\t\t\"0\": {\n\t\t\t\"value\": \"<p><strong>Tutte le aziende italiane<\\/strong>, comprese le grandi imprese e quelle neo-costituite, possono fruire dell'agevolazione sotto forma di credito d'imposta.<\\/p>\"\n\t\t}\n\t},\n\t\"c8b2a21b-2b66-4af7-8289-a37db0fdc916\": {\n\t\t\"0\": {\n\t\t\t\"value\": \"\"\n\t\t}\n\t},\n\t\"caf78a08-2f4f-4561-8c2f-49bb3fb4bc43\": {\n\t\t\"0\": {\n\t\t\t\"value\": \"Credito d'Imposta\"\n\t\t}\n\t},\n\t\"d9221499-0b6f-4663-a122-1054038fc977\": {\n\t\t\"0\": {\n\t\t\t\"value\": \"Tutte le Regioni\"\n\t\t}\n\t},\n\t\"5260368d-ed28-4227-a76d-773461ecce68\": {\n\t\t\"0\": {\n\t\t\t\"value\": \"Tutti\"\n\t\t}\n\t},\n\t\"a8d4dab3-94b7-49b9-9ef1-63193fe5b405\": {\n\t\t\"0\": {\n\t\t\t\"value\": \"2020-12-31 00:00:00\"\n\t\t}\n\t}\n}"," {\n\t\"efa6f15d-0028-45e3-b4b4-e35bff160d47\":  {\n\t\t\"0\":  {\n\t\t\t\"file\": \"images\\/in_primo_piano\\/patent_box_regime_di_tassazione_agevolata_per_beni_materiali_ed_immateriali.jpg\",\n\t\t\t\"title\": \"\",\n\t\t\t\"link\": \"\",\n\t\t\t\"target\": \"0\",\n\t\t\t\"rel\": \"\",\n\t\t\t\"file2\": \"\",\n\t\t\t\"overlay_effect\": \"\",\n\t\t\t\"caption\": \"\",\n\t\t\t\"width\": 758,\n\t\t\t\"height\": 428\n\t\t}\n\t},\n\t\"30c83720-6c74-4373-929c-4c45102c49c5\":  {\n\t\t\"0\":  {\n\t\t\t\"file\": \"images\\/headers\\/patent_box_come_funziona.jpg\",\n\t\t\t\"title\": \"\",\n\t\t\t\"file2\": \"\",\n\t\t\t\"overlay_effect\": \"\",\n\t\t\t\"caption\": \"\",\n\t\t\t\"width\": 2500,\n\t\t\t\"height\": 300\n\t\t}\n\t},\n\t\"27598461-f4cb-4c80-bff9-23aa50f12c0f\":  {\n\t\t\"0\":  {\n\t\t\t\"value\": \"<strong>Patent Box<\\/strong> - <strong>Regime opzionale di tassazione agevolata<\\/strong> per i redditi derivanti dall\\u2019utilizzo diretto o indiretto di alcuni beni immateriali agevolabili.\"\n\t\t}\n\t},\n\t\"f03897c9-d636-4bcb-95bd-fe130f26d4f3\":  {\n\t\t\"0\":  {\n\t\t\t\"value\": \"<div style=\\\"text-align: justify;\\\">I soggetti interessati possono comunicare in via telematica l\\u2019opzione di adesione al regime di tassazione agevolata Patent Box all'Agenzia delle Entrate, compilando l\\u2019apposito modello per il periodo di imposta 2016.<\\/div>\"\n\t\t}\n\t},\n\t\"8808f9b5-4460-4fcb-b623-83e0ba71f315\":  {\n\t\t\"0\":  {\n\t\t\t\"value\": \"<div style=\\\"text-align: justify;\\\">L\\u2019incentivo consiste in una<strong> riduzione del reddito d\\u2019impresa<\\/strong> (base imponibile) <strong>soggetta ad imposte sul reddito (IRPEF e IRES) ed a IRAP.<\\/strong><\\/div>\\r\\n<p style=\\\"text-align: justify;\\\">La variazione in diminuzione del reddito imponibile <strong>\\u00e8 pari ad una percentuale del \\u201creddito agevolabile\\u201d (40% per il 2016 e 50% nei periodi successivi)<\\/strong>: il reddito agevolabile \\u00e8 calcolato mediante apposite formule e software specifico, per ciascun bene immateriale, applicando al reddito prodotto dallo sfruttamento del bene immateriale il risultato del rapporto tra i costi di ricerca e sviluppo sostenuti per il mantenimento, l\\u2019accrescimento e lo sviluppo del bene immateriale ed i costi complessivi sostenuti per il mantenimento, l\\u2019accrescimento e lo sviluppo del bene.<\\/p>\\r\\n<p style=\\\"text-align: justify;\\\"><span style=\\\"text-decoration: underline;\\\"><strong>L'agevolazione \\u00e8 cumulabile con altri regimi di aiuto attualmente in vigore, in particolare con gli incentivi alle startup e con il credito d'imposta per ricerca e sviluppo.<\\/strong><\\/span><\\/p>\"\n\t\t}\n\t},\n\t\"a158776a-7134-49f4-be57-5388c8d8e5ae\":  {\n\t\t\"0\":  {\n\t\t\t\"value\": \"<p style=\\\"text-align: justify;\\\">Sono ammissibili le <strong>spese legate ad attivit\\u00e0 di ricerca e sviluppo finalizzate allo sviluppo, al mantenimento, nonch\\u00e9 all\\u2019accrescimento di valore di software protetto da copyright, brevetti industriali, disegni e i modelli giuridicamente tutelabili e know-how<\\/strong> che si concretizza in un bene giuridicamente tutelabile.<\\/p>\\r\\n<p style=\\\"text-align: justify;\\\">Il beneficio compete non solo per gli intangibles sviluppati internamente dal contribuente, ma anche per <strong>quelli acquisiti presso terzi,<\\/strong> a condizione che l\\u2019impresa beneficiaria svolga su di essi attivit\\u00e0 di mantenimento, accrescimento e sviluppo. Il meccanismo di determinazione dell\\u2019agevolazione \\u00e8, ovviamente, tanto pi\\u00f9 premiante quanto maggiore \\u00e8 l\\u2019attivit\\u00e0 direttamente esercitata nella creazione e sviluppo dei beni tutelabili.<\\/p>\"\n\t\t}\n\t},\n\t\"ce654fde-2155-4c1b-9609-973a14e212ee\":  {\n\t\t\"0\":  {\n\t\t\t\"value\": \"<div style=\\\"text-align: justify;\\\">Possono fruire della tassazione agevolata le<strong> imprese residenti nel territorio italiano<\\/strong>.&nbsp;Non ci sono limitazioni alla forma giuridica e dunque possono accedere le societ\\u00e0 di capitali e la societ\\u00e0 di persona, le imprese individuali e gli enti commerciali.<\\/div>\\r\\n<p style=\\\"text-align: justify;\\\">Sono escluse le imprese assoggettate a procedure di fallimento, liquidazione coatta amministrativa e amministrazione straordinaria.<\\/p>\"\n\t\t}\n\t},\n\t\"c8b2a21b-2b66-4af7-8289-a37db0fdc916\":  {\n\t\t\"0\":  {\n\t\t\t\"value\": \"\"\n\t\t}\n\t},\n\t\"caf78a08-2f4f-4561-8c2f-49bb3fb4bc43\":  {\n\t\t\"0\":  {\n\t\t\t\"value\": \"Tassazione Agevolata\"\n\t\t}\n\t},\n\t\"d9221499-0b6f-4663-a122-1054038fc977\":  {\n\t\t\"0\":  {\n\t\t\t\"value\": \"Nazionale\"\n\t\t}\n\t},\n\t\"5260368d-ed28-4227-a76d-773461ecce68\":  {\n\t\t\"0\":  {\n\t\t\t\"value\": \"Tutti\"\n\t\t}\n\t},\n\t\"a8d4dab3-94b7-49b9-9ef1-63193fe5b405\":  {\n\t\t\"0\":  {\n\t\t\t\"value\": \"\"\n\t\t}\n\t}\n}"," {\n\t\"efa6f15d-0028-45e3-b4b4-e35bff160d47\":  {\n\t\t\"0\":  {\n\t\t\t\"file\": \"images\\/in_primo_piano\\/iperammortamento_industria_4.0-min.jpg\",\n\t\t\t\"title\": \"\",\n\t\t\t\"link\": \"\",\n\t\t\t\"target\": \"0\",\n\t\t\t\"rel\": \"\",\n\t\t\t\"file2\": \"\",\n\t\t\t\"overlay_effect\": \"\",\n\t\t\t\"caption\": \"\",\n\t\t\t\"width\": 758,\n\t\t\t\"height\": 428\n\t\t}\n\t},\n\t\"30c83720-6c74-4373-929c-4c45102c49c5\":  {\n\t\t\"0\":  {\n\t\t\t\"file\": \"images\\/headers\\/superammortamento_e_iperammortamento_1.jpg\",\n\t\t\t\"title\": \"\",\n\t\t\t\"file2\": \"\",\n\t\t\t\"overlay_effect\": \"\",\n\t\t\t\"caption\": \"\",\n\t\t\t\"width\": 2500,\n\t\t\t\"height\": 300\n\t\t}\n\t},\n\t\"27598461-f4cb-4c80-bff9-23aa50f12c0f\":  {\n\t\t\"0\":  {\n\t\t\t\"value\": \"La Legge di Bilancio 2017 ha prorogato il super ammortamento, ossia la maggiorazione del 40% del costo fiscalmente riconosciuto dei <strong>beni strumentali nuovi<\\/strong>, ed ha introdotto<strong> l\\u2019iper ammortamento<\\/strong>, ossia una <strong>maggiorazione del 150% del costo di acquisizione di particolari tipologie di beni funzionali alla trasformazione tecnologica e\\/o digitale delle imprese in chiave Industria 4.0.<\\/strong>\"\n\t\t}\n\t},\n\t\"f03897c9-d636-4bcb-95bd-fe130f26d4f3\":  {\n\t\t\"0\":  {\n\t\t\t\"value\": \"\"\n\t\t}\n\t},\n\t\"8808f9b5-4460-4fcb-b623-83e0ba71f315\":  {\n\t\t\"0\":  {\n\t\t\t\"value\": \"Il beneficio si traduce in un<strong> incremento del costo di acquisizione del bene del 40% o del 150%<\\/strong>, che determina un <strong>aumento della quota annua di ammortamento<\\/strong> (o del canone annuo di leasing) <strong>fiscalmente deducibile.<\\/strong>\"\n\t\t}\n\t},\n\t\"a158776a-7134-49f4-be57-5388c8d8e5ae\":  {\n\t\t\"0\":  {\n\t\t\t\"value\": \"<strong>IPERAMMORTAMENTO<\\/strong><br \\/><br \\/>La <strong>maggiorazione del 150%<\\/strong> si applica per <strong>investimenti effettuati dal 1\\u00b0 gennaio 2017 al 31 dicembre 2017<\\/strong> (o entro il 30 settembre 2018, ma solo a condizione che entro il 31 dicembre 2017 l\\u2019ordine risulti accettato dal venditore e sia stato effettuato il pagamento in acconti in misura pari ad almeno il 20% del costo di acquisizione).<br \\/><br \\/>Sono agevolabili gli investimenti in macchine intelligenti, interconnesse, che possono essere raggruppati in tre categorie:<br \\/>\\r\\n<ul>\\r\\n<li>beni strumentali il cui funzionamento \\u00e8 controllato da sistemi computerizzati o gestito tramite opportuni sensori e azionamenti;<\\/li>\\r\\n<li>sistemi per l\\u2019assicurazione della qualit\\u00e0 e della sostenibilit\\u00e0;<\\/li>\\r\\n<li>dispositivi per l\\u2019interazione uomo macchina e per il miglioramento dell\\u2019ergonomia e della sicurezza del posto di lavoro in logica \\\"4.0\\\".<\\/li>\\r\\n<\\/ul>\\r\\n<p><strong>SUPERAMMORTAMENTO BENI IMMATERIALI<\\/strong><br \\/><br \\/>Sono agevolabili gli <strong>investimenti in beni immateriali<\\/strong> (software, sistemi e system integration, piattaforme e applicazioni) <strong>connessi a investimenti in beni materiali \\u00abIndustria 4.0\\u00bb.<\\/strong><\\/p>\\r\\n<p>Il beneficio \\u00e8 cumulabile con:<\\/p>\\r\\n<ul>\\r\\n<li>Nuova Sabatini<\\/li>\\r\\n<li>Credito d\\u2019imposta per attivit\\u00e0 di Ricerca e Sviluppo<\\/li>\\r\\n<li>Patent Box<\\/li>\\r\\n<li>Incentivi alla patrimonializzazione delle imprese (ACE)<\\/li>\\r\\n<li>Incentivi agli investimenti in Start up e PMI innovative<\\/li>\\r\\n<li>Fondo Centrale di Garanzia<\\/li>\\r\\n<\\/ul>\"\n\t\t}\n\t},\n\t\"ce654fde-2155-4c1b-9609-973a14e212ee\":  {\n\t\t\"0\":  {\n\t\t\t\"value\": \"<p><strong>IPERAMMORTAMENTO<\\/strong><br \\/><br \\/>Sono ammessi all\\u2019agevolazione unicamente <strong>i titolari di reddito d\\u2019impresa, indipendentemente dalla natura giuridica, dalla dimensione aziendale e dal settore economico in cui operano.<\\/strong><\\/p>\\r\\n<p>Sono ammesse all\\u2019agevolazione <strong>sia le imprese residenti nel territorio dello Stato che le stabili organizzazioni nel territorio dello Stato di soggetti non residenti.<\\/strong> Sono ammessi gli enti non commerciali con riferimento all\\u2019attivit\\u00e0 commerciale eventualmente esercitata.<br \\/><br \\/><strong>SUPERAMMORTAMENTO BENI IMMATERIALI<\\/strong><\\/p>\\r\\n<p>Per i <strong>soggetti imprenditoriali che beneficiano di iperammortamento<\\/strong> \\u00e8 possibile dedurre dall\\u2019imponibile un ammontare<strong> pari al 140%<\\/strong> (come nel caso del super ammortamento) del costo di acquisizione di alcuni beni immateriali specificamente individuati dal legislatore. Le scadenze temporali sono le medesime previste per l\\u2019iperammortamento.<\\/p>\"\n\t\t}\n\t},\n\t\"c8b2a21b-2b66-4af7-8289-a37db0fdc916\":  {\n\t\t\"0\":  {\n\t\t\t\"value\": \"\"\n\t\t}\n\t},\n\t\"caf78a08-2f4f-4561-8c2f-49bb3fb4bc43\":  {\n\t\t\"0\":  {\n\t\t\t\"value\": \"Deduzione IRES \\/ IRPEF\"\n\t\t}\n\t},\n\t\"d9221499-0b6f-4663-a122-1054038fc977\":  {\n\t\t\"0\":  {\n\t\t\t\"value\": \"Tutte le Regioni\"\n\t\t}\n\t},\n\t\"5260368d-ed28-4227-a76d-773461ecce68\":  {\n\t\t\"0\":  {\n\t\t\t\"value\": \"Tutti\"\n\t\t}\n\t},\n\t\"a8d4dab3-94b7-49b9-9ef1-63193fe5b405\":  {\n\t\t\"0\":  {\n\t\t\t\"value\": \"2018-09-30 00:00:00\"\n\t\t}\n\t}\n}","{\n\t\"efa6f15d-0028-45e3-b4b4-e35bff160d47\": {\n\t\t\"0\": {\n\t\t\t\"file\": \"images\\/in_primo_piano\\/bando_emilia_romagna_fiere_estero-min_1.jpg\",\n\t\t\t\"title\": \"\",\n\t\t\t\"link\": \"\",\n\t\t\t\"target\": \"0\",\n\t\t\t\"rel\": \"\",\n\t\t\t\"file2\": \"\",\n\t\t\t\"overlay_effect\": \"\",\n\t\t\t\"caption\": \"\",\n\t\t\t\"width\": 758,\n\t\t\t\"height\": 428\n\t\t}\n\t},\n\t\"30c83720-6c74-4373-929c-4c45102c49c5\": {\n\t\t\"0\": {\n\t\t\t\"file\": \"images\\/headers\\/header_formazione_4.0-min.jpg\",\n\t\t\t\"title\": \"\",\n\t\t\t\"file2\": \"\",\n\t\t\t\"overlay_effect\": \"\",\n\t\t\t\"caption\": \"\",\n\t\t\t\"width\": 2500,\n\t\t\t\"height\": 300\n\t\t}\n\t},\n\t\"27598461-f4cb-4c80-bff9-23aa50f12c0f\": {\n\t\t\"0\": {\n\t\t\t\"value\": \"<strong>Credito d'imposta a favore di tutte le imprese, per attivit\\u00e0 di formazione dirette ad acquisire e consolidare le conoscenze tecnologiche \\u00abIndustria 4.0\\u00bb.<\\/strong>\"\n\t\t}\n\t},\n\t\"f03897c9-d636-4bcb-95bd-fe130f26d4f3\": {\n\t\t\"0\": {\n\t\t\t\"value\": \"Il credito d\\u2019imposta sar\\u00e0 utilizzabile<strong> esclusivamente in compensazione<\\/strong> a decorrere dal periodo d\\u2019imposta successivo a quello in cui i costi sono sostenuti, presentando il modello F24 esclusivamente attraverso i servizi telematici messi a disposizione dall\\u2019Agenzia delle Entrate.\"\n\t\t}\n\t},\n\t\"8808f9b5-4460-4fcb-b623-83e0ba71f315\": {\n\t\t\"0\": {\n\t\t\t\"value\": \"ll bonus \\u00e8 attributo nella <strong>misura del 40% delle spese ammissibili,<\\/strong> con un <strong>massimo di 300.000 euro<\\/strong> per ciascuna impresa beneficiaria.\"\n\t\t}\n\t},\n\t\"a158776a-7134-49f4-be57-5388c8d8e5ae\": {\n\t\t\"0\": {\n\t\t\t\"value\": \"<p><span class=\\\"oe_form_text_content\\\">Sono ammissibili al credito d\\u2019imposta le attivit\\u00e0 di formazione finalizzate all\\u2019acquisizione o al consolidamento, da parte del personale dipendente dell\\u2019impresa, delle competenze nelle tecnologie rilevanti per la realizzazione del processo di trasformazione tecnologica e digitale delle imprese previsto dal \\u201cPiano nazionale Impresa 4.0\\u201d. <\\/span><\\/p>\\r\\n<p><span class=\\\"oe_form_text_content\\\">Costituiscono in particolare attivit\\u00e0 ammissibili al credito d\\u2019imposta le attivit\\u00e0 di formazione concernenti le seguenti tecnologie: <\\/span><\\/p>\\r\\n<ul>\\r\\n<li><span class=\\\"oe_form_text_content\\\">big data e analisi dei dati; <\\/span><\\/li>\\r\\n<li><span class=\\\"oe_form_text_content\\\">cloud e fog computing; <\\/span><\\/li>\\r\\n<li><span class=\\\"oe_form_text_content\\\">cyber security; <\\/span><\\/li>\\r\\n<li><span class=\\\"oe_form_text_content\\\">simulazione e sistemi cyber-fisici; <\\/span><\\/li>\\r\\n<li><span class=\\\"oe_form_text_content\\\">prototipazione rapida; <\\/span><\\/li>\\r\\n<li><span class=\\\"oe_form_text_content\\\">sistemi di visualizzazione, realt\\u00e0 virtuale e realt\\u00e0 aumentata; <\\/span><\\/li>\\r\\n<li><span class=\\\"oe_form_text_content\\\">robotica avanzata e collaborativa; <\\/span><\\/li>\\r\\n<li><span class=\\\"oe_form_text_content\\\">interfaccia uomo macchina; <\\/span><\\/li>\\r\\n<li><span class=\\\"oe_form_text_content\\\">manifattura additiva (o stampa tridimensionale); <\\/span><\\/li>\\r\\n<li><span class=\\\"oe_form_text_content\\\">internet delle cose e delle macchine; <\\/span><\\/li>\\r\\n<li><span class=\\\"oe_form_text_content\\\">integrazione digitale dei processi aziendali.<\\/span><\\/li>\\r\\n<\\/ul>\"\n\t\t}\n\t},\n\t\"ce654fde-2155-4c1b-9609-973a14e212ee\": {\n\t\t\"0\": {\n\t\t\t\"value\": \"Possono accedere al credito d\\u2019imposta:<br \\/>\\r\\n<ul>\\r\\n<li>Imprese residenti in Italia, indipendentemente dalla natura giuridica, dal settore economico di appartenenza, dalla dimensione, dal regime contabile e dal sistema di determinazione del reddito ai fini fiscali.<\\/li>\\r\\n<li>Enti non commerciali residenti svolgenti attivit\\u00e0 commerciali rilevanti ai fini del reddito d'impresa.<\\/li>\\r\\n<li>Imprese residenti all'estero con stabili organizzazioni sul territorio italiano.<\\/li>\\r\\n<\\/ul>\"\n\t\t}\n\t},\n\t\"c8b2a21b-2b66-4af7-8289-a37db0fdc916\": {\n\t\t\"0\": {\n\t\t\t\"value\": \"\"\n\t\t}\n\t},\n\t\"caf78a08-2f4f-4561-8c2f-49bb3fb4bc43\": {\n\t\t\"0\": {\n\t\t\t\"value\": \"Credito D'Imposta\"\n\t\t}\n\t},\n\t\"d9221499-0b6f-4663-a122-1054038fc977\": {\n\t\t\"0\": {\n\t\t\t\"value\": \"Tutte le Regioni\"\n\t\t}\n\t},\n\t\"5260368d-ed28-4227-a76d-773461ecce68\": {\n\t\t\"0\": {\n\t\t\t\"value\": \"Tutti i Settori\"\n\t\t}\n\t},\n\t\"a8d4dab3-94b7-49b9-9ef1-63193fe5b405\": {\n\t\t\"0\": {\n\t\t\t\"value\": \"\"\n\t\t}\n\t}\n}"]
```

Comment: do not stringify, thats it

Comment: What should `if (JSON.stringify(res))` do? Where do you think you're parsing JSON? Why do you think you have an array?

Comment: please share the exact json

Comment: @bubbles it does not woek even if I remove stringfy

Comment: @nitishk72 that the exact json

Comment: the second problem is that `res` is an object and not an array, so you can access the value like `res['efa6f15d-0028-45e3-b4b4-e35bff160d47']`

Comment: @chrispbacon I'm sure I have an array because "myURL" returns an array of that JSONs type

Comment: @bubbles res['efa6f15d-0028-45e3-b4b4-e35bff160d47'] is always undefined

Comment: please post the output of `JSON.stringify(res)`

Comment: If this is really the output (which I doubt since it's an array, not a string; you need to `const data = JSON.parse(foo[0])`. However, again, if this is really the output, you should change the API's response to return something more sensible.

Answer (score 1):

Under EcmaScript 5, you can use `Object.entries` and create an array of keys and its values to iterate like you want in your question:

```
var words = {
   "efa6f15d-0028-45e3-b4b4-e35bff160d47":{ id: 1   },
   "30c83720-6c74-4373-929c-4c45102c49c5":{  },
   "27598461-f4cb-4c80-bff9-23aa50f12c0f":{  },
   "f03897c9-d636-4bcb-95bd-fe130f26d4f3":{  },
   "8808f9b5-4460-4fcb-b623-83e0ba71f315":{  },
   "a158776a-7134-49f4-be57-5388c8d8e5ae":{  },
   "ce654fde-2155-4c1b-9609-973a14e212ee":{  },
   "c8b2a21b-2b66-4af7-8289-a37db0fdc916":{  },
   "caf78a08-2f4f-4561-8c2f-49bb3fb4bc43":{  },
   "d9221499-0b6f-4663-a122-1054038fc977":{  },
   "5260368d-ed28-4227-a76d-773461ecce68":{  },
   "a8d4dab3-94b7-49b9-9ef1-63193fe5b405":{  }
};

const result = Object.keys(words)
    .map(key => {            
        let obj = {};
        obj[key] = words[key];
        return obj;
    });

console.log(result);
```

UPDATE:

You have an object, not array. So this code `arra.length` will have value `undefined` because this code `res as any[]` does not creates an array. It is just tries to cast your object to array. So try to use the above code to create an array.

So you should iterate your object using `for - in` loop and your code can look like this:

```
for (let key in words) {
    if (words.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log(`The key of object is ${ key }, the value of object is:`, words[key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: But my problema is that I can't read the keys of the json I get...

Comment: @Francesco please, see my updated answer. You can't use `Object.length`, but you can use `Object.keys.length`